# ActiveX control -Single-threaded apartments

Tags: c#, windows

I'd downloaded the facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-winforms-sample project example,

This project is working well when I do a testing, then I created new project follow that exmaple all steps.

I get error message when I do testing on my new project.

```
Line : webBrowser1 = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
```

Error Message :

ActiveX control '8856f961-340a-11d0-a96b-00c04fd705a2' cannot be instantiated because the current thread is not in a single-threaded apartment.this

Comment: put `[STAThread]` attribute to your `Main` method

Comment: Yes, the default Program.cs file, is already has :

[STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new MainForm());
        }


I'm not sure you want me put [STAThread] to this file (Program.cs) or other MainForm.cs?

Comment: Then make sure you don't create the `WebBroser` in a thread other that ui thread.

Comment: I was created webBrowser in MainForm.cs, maybe I'm not deep in thread process, Can you explain to me a little bit about thread.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check whether ur main() function has `[StaThread]` attribute
2. Check whether u r using the following  line inside Method which is called multiple times.

`Line : webBrowser1 = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();`

Comment: You refer to MainForm.cs ? , because firstly I run MainFrom.cs

Comment: No, i mean in "Program.cs" file.